# IIS 10 and PHP 7.3 cant upload 4M file in one POST request

Tags: php, iis, file-size, file-upload

I have changed the maxfile size in the php.ini settings, but i do not know how to change it in the IIS 10 config.

My hphinfo:
[image]

I am getting the error `1` in the $_FILE array (which as I understand means that the request size exceeds the max allowed.

I am sending smaller files (ie 1M or 2M without any problems)

The POST request is generated by my software (it is an ucontroller controlled device) and here is no browser involved in it.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error? Also what is your upload_max_filesize value set to in php.ini?

Comment: @Jarco upload_max_filesize -> 8M I think it is IIS problem. The error is 1 in the "error" ($_FILE variable)

Answer (score 2):

From: https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb306.aspx

> By default, IIS web server allows for limited file size to be uploaded
>   to the web server. For IIS 6 and IIS 7, the default maximum file
>   upload size is 4 MB and 28.6 MB respectively. IIS 7 returns a 404
>   error (HTTP Error 404.13 - CONTENT_LENGTH_TOO_LARGE) if someone
>   uploads something larger than 30MB. In order to allow for larger file
>   size uploads, a few server changes are required.

Modify the maxAllowedContentLength setting in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

With the above maxAllowedContentLength, users can upload files that are 2 GB in size. This setting will work right away without restart IIS services.

Comment: Thank yoy - but iis does not have this section, and ignores it when I add it. I did it before asking the question. Do you know how to add it (and where) in the IIS10?

Comment: Here are some debugging steps which might help: http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-debug.htm

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the "php.ini" file, where "upload_max_filesize" is set to "2M" by default.
If you change "2M" by e.g. "10M", then your POST request shall work. Otherwise, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: they say they already changed the max file size in php.ini.  The comment says upload_max_filesize is set to 8MB